# Is my spelling of "A Túrin Turambar turún' ambartanen" correct?

Tags: tolkiens-legendarium, tolkien-languages

When near the end of "Children of Hurin" Nienor screams:

> "Farewell, O twice beloved! A Turin Turambar turun' ambartanen, master
>   of doom by doom mastered! O happy to be dead!"

As it is in Quenya, I presume it would be written down in Certhas Daeron, because of the age? I've written it below but is this correct?

[image]

Comment: I think the best thing to do is to get it tattooed on yourself, then people will fall over themselves to correct it for you

Comment: I think the elvish is missing the´an´ of the word ´ambartanen´. I don´t know elvish, but every character seems to be directly translated to another. The last word would translate to ´ambarten´ and not ´ambartanen´. Whether the entire translation is correct, I cannot say.

Comment: @Mixxiphoid yea u are right! thanks for insight!

Comment: Would this maybe be a better fit for the Conlang Stack?

Answer (score 5):

I'm not sure you're using the correct 'r' rune. In the inscription on Balin's tomb, Tolkien uses #12 rather than #29 (referring to the Angerthas table in Apendix E of the LotR). Same for your 'n': on Balin's tomb, #22 is used. You're using #12.

For 'mb', I'm pretty sure #7 should be used, instead of #6#2.

You've got your 'u' and your 'ú' the other way round. Again, refer to Balin's tomb - it has examples of both.

As Mixxiphoid points out, you're missing the 'an' in 'ambartanen'.

Not sure if there are any other issues.

Also, there's no reason why you need to use the *Certar* rather than the *Tengwar*. Both were in use during the First Age. The difference was in their use:

> The *Tengwar* were devised for writing with brush or pen [..]. The *Certar* were devised and mostly used only for scratched or incised inscription. (Tolkien, LotR, Appendix E II)

This is how I would do it, I think:
[image]

Comment: Good explanation. It might be useful to include the correct spelling, given your reasoning.

Comment: Hey! Thanks for the answer! The problem with the answer is that on Balin's tomb the writing language is Angerthas Moria, and not Certhas Daeron. Angerthas Moria was used in second age, where dwarves suited the cirth to their own language. Certar i want to use, as it if was inscribed on some runestone. And, thank you for showing the mistake of missing AN!

Comment: @Bora having dug through Appendix E some more, Tolkien states that runes #13-17 and #23-28 were the ones introduced in the 2nd Age. #13,#15 and #35 changed their sound between the ages. Presumably, as far as the other runes are concerned, you can trust Balin's tomb. Unless you have another example of the runes written?

Comment: @Gnemlock I'm not sure I have the correct spelling, but I added my best attempt.

Comment: Note that u and ú were not only switched around in the original, but also incorrectly distributed: it had the same rune in _Túrin_ as in _Turambar_ (as though it were _*Túrambar_).

Comment: @Galastel I used info from tolkiengateway.net , but i dont know how correct that is.

Comment: @Janus yes, i missed that one, fixing it now